# Освобождение памяти, используемой картинкой, для замены при конвертации

Tags: c#, изображения, память, bitmap

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть класс конвертирующий изображение одной библиотеки (FireDraw) в изображение другой (GDI+). У меня случилась проблема, что при замене старых данных на новые они всё ещё занимают память.
Пожалуйста, подскажите способ освобождать память.

```
public static Image ToGDI(Buffer buffer) {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(buffer.Width, buffer.Height);

        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, buffer.Width, buffer.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        data.Scan0 = buffer.Data;
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        return bmp;
}
```

Если убрать строку `data.Scan0 = buffer.Data;`, утечка памяти не случается, поэтому проблема в ней.
Место, где вызывается метод

```
public void Render() {
        if(f.IsDisposed)
            return;

        if(pic.Image != null)
            pic.Image.Dispose();
        pic.Image = FireDraw.Convert.ToGDI(graphics.Buffer);
}
```

Comment: А откуда `buffer` берется?

Comment: Александр, это не важно. Важно то, что он полностью заполнен данными и не вызывает утечек памяти.

Comment: Надо видеть полностью код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было вместо всего этого писать это:

```
public static Image ToGDI(Buffer buffer) {
    return new Bitmap(buffer.Width, buffer.Height, buffer.Stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, buffer.Data);
}
```